restrict multi-picklist choices in screen flow
In my Salesforce screen flow design, I'm utilizing a multi-picklist field. I want to limit the selection to only five options out of the 91 choices available in the multi-picklist field. How can I achieve this restriction within the Screen flow?
For instance, suppose I have a country field with 91 choices. I wish to restrict users from selecting more than five countries. If they choose more than five, I want to trigger an error. However, selecting fewer than five is acceptable.
Appreciate the support. Thank you.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393459&type=1 is a good start

I would do the following
OPTION 1

Install the UnofficalSf.com Manage MultiSelect Picklists package. (If you're not aware of UnofficalSf.com, now is a good time. There are tremendous resources here)

Then, your flow becomes simple, no loops.

Assign the user-selected MSP values to a record variable in the relevant field. (Unless the user selection is already in a record variable)
Use an Apex action to pass these values to the apex action

objectApiName - your object (e.g. Lead)
fieldApiName - e.g. Country__c
operation = ReturnStrngCollection
curRecord = the recordVariable


The apex action returns selectedValuesList that the flow sees as a String collection.
Use an Assignment element with operator Count to get the selectedValuesList size, place the result in a variable countrySelectedMspCount
Use a decision element to see if countrySelectedMspCount > 5

This is an unmanaged package and you can inspect the source in GitHub
OPTION 2
Use a formula resource that exploits the REGEX function to see if 5 or more semi-colons (as semi-colons are the delimiter for a MSP field). An example regex (untested) can be found on stackoverflow
